# What approaches are available for allowing Azure AD B2C users to GET and POST data to a M365 environment via Graph API?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Per the docs, there is no 'out of the box' way to enable Azure AD B2C users to interact with the M365 environment associated with the Azure AD tenant that was used to create the Azure AD B2C tenant.

> Azure AD B2C can't be used to authenticate users for Microsoft 365.

Source:
[Can I use Azure AD B2C to provide social login (Facebook and Google+) into Microsoft 365?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#can-i-use-azure-ad-b2c-to-provide-social-login--facebook-and-google---into-microsoft-365-)

But I still need to be able to provide this functionality, i.e `GET` and `POST` requests to M365 via the Graph API.

To be clear, this is what I have achieved so far:

- Azure AD B2C users can login
- Azure AD users can login and interact with *their own* M365 environment via Graph API
  (to enable this, I added the Azure AD tenant as an identity provider, per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow))

What I have not yet been able to figure out is:

- How can the Azure AD B2C users interact with the M365 environment associated with the Azure AD tenant?
  (that created the Azure AD B2C tenant)

To illustrate a use case for this requirement:

- `Company_A` wants to enable external contractors to be able to submit compliance documents to them
- They set up Azure AD B2C and create accounts for their external contractors
- They set up a Node.js/Express web app on Azure
- External contractors can now login to a web app and view forms designed to submit data and attachments
- How can those forms send data and attachments to a Document Library in `Company_A`'s M365 environment?

I have been pondering this issue for a while and can't conceptualise a mental or technical model of how this can be achieved.

Google searching related phrases doesn't produce any relevant content.

I am hoping someone will have the knowledge and experience to be able to say:

> You will need to follow THIS paradigm which is documented HERE and involves doing THIS

**Edit:**

I am reading articles like these:

[Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

which talks about scenarios where:

> apps that have a signed-in user present may also need to call Microsoft Graph under their own identity

and contemplating adding `Application Permissions` (as opposed to `Delegated Permissions`) to my Azure AD B2C application registration.

Just to test the idea, I have added `Sites.ReadWrite.All` as an `Application Permission` and granted `Admin Consent` for that permission.  How would I define this scope (`Sites.ReadWrite.All`) to be associated with the 'home' Azure AD tenant (as opposed to the Azure AD B2C tenant)?  I am using [msal-node](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) which has a method named [getAuthCodeURL()](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_node.confidentialclientapplication.html#getauthcodeurl) where you pass through the scopes required.  I am assuming if I just added `Sites.ReadWrite.All` it would default to being applied to the Azure AD B2C tenant, rather than the desired Azure AD tenant?

Answer (score 2):

M365 doesn’t exist in an Azure AD B2C tenant, you cannot apply a license for Office there. This simply isn’t possible.

For Graph API, you cannot use B2C issued tokens to call it. You must use underlying AAD Tokens to access it. Your server would need to perform Azure AD client credentials flow against the Azure AD endpoint of your AAD B2C tenant and ask for a token to Graph API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Microsoft service `scopes` only apply to the underlying Azure AD endpoints of your AAD B2C tenant. They won’t mean anything at the AAD B2C login endpoints. Hence, the differentiation is made by the endpoint used.

An Azure AD B2C tenant has both endpoints:

AAD: `login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId`

B2C: `b2clogin.com/tenantId`

Since M365 env does not exist for B2C tenants, the MS Graph API is only useful to R/W user data. But, for this, you could just use the B2C user flows to R/W user profile data, and return user profile data into the B2C token, so you don’t have go call MS Graph API. This is actually the intended usage pattern.